# Quartz job for Grails only fires once

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to setup a cron job in my Grails web application using the [Quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz). I am currently simply trying to get a test job to execute once every second using the following code:

```
class TestJob {
    private int counter = 0
    static triggers = {
        simple repeatInterval: 1000
    }

    def execute() {
        // execute job
        counter += 1
        System.out.println("Testing the cron " + counter)
    }
}
```

However, when I run the application I only see the initial output of the first `execute()` call twice: once immediately before I am alerted that the server is running, and once immediately after.

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
Testing the cron 1
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/QuartzTest
Testing the cron 1
```

Does anyone know why my Quartz job might not be firing correctly? I have tried using a cron instead of simple as well as using varying parameters, time intervals, etc. Nothing has made a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I had similar issues. You are not allowed to use `System.out.println` from within a quartz-job. Try to use `log.error`.

Comment: Hmm... I had exactly the same behaviour, but changing to log.error made no difference. Instead, changing "counter" to be static fixed the problem (even when using println), though I don't understand why that would affect job triggering.

Comment: Worked for me. 
By the way why such a behavior?

Comment: Just an update, I'm using version 1.0-RC9 of the plugin (which uses Quartz 2.2) and println works in 2 jobs - 1 in grails-app/jobs and another I define and schedule using the scheduler grabbed from  JobManagerService.

Comment: Wow... Are there other things that are not allowed like this in a Job? This is quite scary. My job is going to call some services methods. I'm not 100% sure about how they are implemented. Will they break the job? (I'm using 1.0-RC9)

Answer (score 1):

Simple triggers have a repeatCount field.  Set it to -1 for indefinite executions:

```
simple name: "testName", repeatInterval: 1000, repeatCount: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation all examples have a `name` parameter in the triggers block:

```
static triggers = {
      simple name: "testName", repeatInterval: 1000      
}
```

I'd give that a shot first, even though the docs also say that a default value will be used if it's not given.

Comment: I actually originally had the name parameter, as well as the startDelay parameter with the trigger as well, it still only seemed to execute twice.

Comment: In the docs I just found the line that "By default, jobs will not be executed when running under the test environment." I'm not sure what that means because clearly it runs twice.

Comment: Yes, I saw that as well. As my output shows though, my environment should be set to development, so that shouldn't be causing the issue.

Comment: Actually, looks like it is only getting executed once, not twice like I thought. See updated code to see: I added a counter that doesn't increment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and came to this conclusion:

You can use System.out.println in a Quartz Job. You have to separate out the methods with the print lines from the execute method. I had no luck with just calling just one method, but when calling two other methods, it repeats with the print lines correctly:

```
class TestJob {
    static triggers = {
    simple name: 'testTrigger', startDelay: 1000, repeatInterval: 1000, repeatCount: -1
    }

    def execute() {
        exampleMethod()
        anotherMethod()
    }

    def exampleMethod(){
        System.out.println("test")
    }

    def anotherMethod(){
        System.out.println("another method")
   }
}
```

here is the output:

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 2 source files.....
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI


Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

test
another method
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/
test
another method
test
another method
test
another method
test
another method
test
another method
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I didnt need to have two methods. The trick is having two printlns. This is so bizarre.