# Using Quartz Plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am new to use Quartz plugin in Grails and want to run simple application. I used the following codes (form quartz plugin docs) but it only runs once. Any Idea? Should I setup anything?

Thanks

```
class MyJob {
    static triggers = { simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 60000, repeatInterval: 1000 }
    def group = "MyGroup"

    def execute(){
    println "Running Job!"
  }
}
```

Comment: More info, please. Is the class in /grails-app/jobs? And set startDelay to 10000 to prevent waiting 1 min.

Comment: yes, its in  /grails-app/jobs and the quartz plugin is 0.4.2 (I should use this version)

Comment: I can just say, that you shouldn't setup anything.

Comment: It might this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11477301/901257

Comment: Thank! But their solution didn't solve mine

Comment: I just copied your code into a test project and it ran repeatedly once per second.  Grails 2.1.0 and plugin version 0.4.2.  The latest plugin version also worked fine.

Comment: That's weird! I am using Grails 2.1.0 with STS on windows platform. but nothing works!

Comment: Very weird that it runs one time.  What happens if you update the plugin dependency to `compile ":quartz:1.0-RC2"`?

Comment: I switched to ":quartz:1.0-RC2", but still doesn't work :-(

Comment: This is my console output!

| Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 2 source files.....
| Running Grails application
Running Job!
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/QT
Running Job!

As you can see println is working, because it writes two times "Running Job!", But it couldn't reapeat the job!. I am not sure but there could be a bug 
for windows platform ?!

Comment: I was on windows as well.  Are you adding quartz to an existing project?  If so try creating a new project, install quartz plugin, then copy the same Job over to the new project.  If it works there you know it's something specific to your project, if it doesn't work there then you know it's something with your environment.  Also, try it from the command line instead of from the IDE to rule out any possible IDE-related issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15423/discussion-between-proflux-and-reza)

Comment: Try quartz 1.0.2 version.  try to work with other way of triggering the job.  e.g. consider cron expressions. http://grails.asia/grails-quartz-plugin-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the "new Date()" to println and it now works!

```
class MyJob {
    static triggers = { simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 60000, repeatInterval: 1000 , repeatCount:-1}
    def group = "MyGroup"

    def execute(){
    println "Running Job!"+new Date()
  }
}
```

It **seems** to me that the quartz makes some **optimization**, when the state of job is constant it runs it once!

Comment: It looks like it was triggered few times, but GGTS (which I think you were using) has an optimalization mechanism in console to prevent printing the same communicate few times, so it only printed "Running Job!" once.


After adding *new Date()* to output the communicate was different each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run job several times then specify repeatCount in simple trigger definition:

> repeatCount — trigger will fire job execution (1 + repeatCount) times and stop after that (specify 0 here to have one-shot job or -1 to repeat job executions indefinitely)

Comment: The default repeat count for the Quartz plugin is -1.  Check out [TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugins/quartz/config/TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy) for full details.

Comment: I also set the repeatCount (:10) but couldn't get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a **cron** inside your triggers in order to configure WHEN your job will be executed:

```
static triggers = {
    cron name: 'mySimpleCron', cronExpression: "0 30 15 * * ?"
}
```

This will run your job every day at 15:30:00.

Another examples:

1.Fire every minute starting at 2pm and ending at 2:05pm, every day:

```
cronExpression: "0 0-5 14 * * ?"
```

2.Fire at 10:15am every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday:

```
cronExpression: "0 15 10 ? * MON-FRI"
```

The sintax of the **7 terms** expression is:

```
* * * * * * *
| | | | | | |_ Year [optional]
| | | | | |_ Day of Week, 1-7 or SUN-SAT, ?
| | | | |_ Month, 1-12 or JAN-DEC
| | | |_ Day of Month, 1-31, ?
| | |_ Hour [0-23]
| |_ Minute [0-59] 
|_ Second [0-59]
```

It's easier to define job execution behavior on this way and you'll have more options to configure just by changing your expression and not the entire code.

More information in these links:

**[CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)**

**[Quartz plugin for Grails - Reference Documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/)**